# ¿porque no elimina registros de la BD mysql mi pagina JSP?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

Mi aplicación si inserta registros:

```
sta.executeUpdate("insert into usuarios values('"+cod+"','"+nom+"','"+edad+"','"+sex+"','"+pas+"')");
```

se ven reflejados los cambios, al añadir uno nuevo

pero al querer eliminar no lo hace:

```
String cod=request.getParameter("txtCod");       
Connection cnx=null;
Statement sta=null;
ResultSet rs=null;
try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    cnx=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://remotemysql.com:3306/HMDm6PvUzZ?user=HMDm6PvUzZ&password=28XiYDPVoC");
    sta=cnx.createStatement();
    sta=cnx.createStatement();
    sta.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE CodUsu='"+cod+"'");
    request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request,response);
    sta.close();
    rs.close();
    cnx.close();
} catch(Exception e) {
    out.println(e+"");
}
```

al refrescar la pagina de inicio, no elimina el registro, ¿cual será la razón?

Comment: Saludos te sugiero cambiar esto: executeUpdate("DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE CodUsu='"+cod+"'"); ....por executeUpdate("DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE CodUsu ="+cod);....

Comment: muchas gracias, lo intente, pero sigue sin eliminar

Comment: Imprime en consola el "Cod" que quieres eliminar y verifica si trae data y existe en tu bd.

Comment: La base de datos tiene habilitado el autocommit??? normalmente viene por defecto habilitado.

Comment: Prueba a ejecutar el forward fuera del try - catch o al menos despues de haber terminado con la BD